# When check box is clicked layout breaks. Jquery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am working on a to-do list using Jquery and Ajax. I have a click event to display when the tasks are completed. When the click event fires the layout breaks. The only way to bring it back to normal is to refresh the page.

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

When I mark the task as completed the to do list goes from column to row, and I can no longer click the check box to turn the task to an active task.

This is the click event:

```
$(".mark-complete").on('click', function (e) {
    $('.task').each(function (i, el) {
      if ($(this).find('.mark-complete').prop('checked')) {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'rgba(36, 236, 36, 0.116)');
      }
    })
  });
```

```js
var getAndDisplayAllTasks = function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://altcademy-to-do-list-api.herokuapp.com/tasks?api_key=495",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response, textStatus) {
      // empty the list
      $("#todo-list").empty();

      // check if the task is completed



      // loop through the tasks and display them
      response.tasks.forEach(function(task) {
        console.log(task);
        $("#todo-list").append(
          '<div class="task row"><p class="col-xs-8">' +
          task.content +
          '</p><button class="delete" data-id="' +
          task.id +
          '">Delete</button><input type="checkbox" class="mark-complete" data-id="' +
          task.id +
          '"' +
          (task.completed ? "checked" : "") +
          ">"
        );

      });
    },
    error: function(request, textStatus, errorMessage) {
      console.log(errorMessage);
    },
  });
};

var createTask = function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://altcademy-to-do-list-api.herokuapp.com/tasks?api_key=495",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({
      task: {
        content: $("#new-task-content").val(),
      },
    }),
    success: function(response, textStatus) {
      $("#new-task-content").val();
      getAndDisplayAllTasks();
    },
    error: function(request, textStatus, errorMessage) {
      console.log(errorMessage);
    },
  });
};

var deleteTask = function(id) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "DELETE",
    url: "https://altcademy-to-do-list-api.herokuapp.com/tasks/" +
      id +
      "?api_key=495",
    success: function(response, textStatus) {
      getAndDisplayAllTasks();
    },
    error: function(request, textStatus, errorMessage) {
      console.log(errorMessage);
    },
  });
};

var markTaskComplete = function(id) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: "https://altcademy-to-do-list-api.herokuapp.com/tasks/" +
      id +
      "/mark_complete?api_key=495",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response, textStatus) {
      response.task.completed = true;
      getAndDisplayAllTasks();
    },
    error: function(request, textStatus, errorMessage) {
      console.log(errorMessage);
    },
  });
};

var markTaskActive = function(id) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: "https://altcademy-to-do-list-api.herokuapp.com/tasks/" +
      id +
      "/mark_active?api_key=495",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response, textStatus) {
      // show the active tasks
      response.task.completed = false;
      getAndDisplayAllTasks();
    },
    error: function(request, textStatus, errorMessage) {
      console.log(errorMessage);
    },
  });
};


$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("change", ".mark-complete", function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      //toggle the completed class if completed
      // toggle line through for the paragraph
      $(this).parent().parent().addClass("task-completed");
      markTaskComplete($(this).data("id"));
    } else {
      markTaskActive($(this).data("id"));
    }
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".delete", function() {
    deleteTask($(this).data("id"));
  });

  $(".mark-complete").on('click', function(e) {
    $('.task').each(function(i, el) {
      if ($(this).find('.mark-complete').prop('checked')) {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'rgba(36, 236, 36, 0.116)');
      }
    })
  });



  $("#create-task").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    createTask();
  });

  $("#active-btn").on("click", function() {
    $(".task").each(function(i, el) {
      if ($(this).find(".mark-complete").prop("checked")) {
        $(this).hide();
      } else {
        $(this).show();
      }
    });
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(this).removeClass("active");
  });

  $("#completed-btn").on("click", function() {
    // find all the tasks that are checked
    $(".task").each(function(i, el) {
      if ($(this).find(".mark-complete").prop("checked") !== true) {
        $(this).hide();
      } else {
        $(this).show();
      }
    });
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(this).removeClass("active");
  });

  $("#all-btn").on("click", function() {
    $('.task').each(function(i, el) {
      $(this).show();
    })
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(this).removeClass("active");
  });

  // check to see if .mark-complete is checked
  //if it is the background color of the row should be green


  getAndDisplayAllTasks();
});

//show completed
```

```css
h2 {
  color: blue;
}

.delete {
  margin-right: 5px;
}


/* When Task is completed line through div */

.row,
.task,
.task-completed {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.mark-complete:checked~.task-completed {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.task-completed {
  background-color: rgba(36, 236, 36, 0.116);
}

.line-through {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.656);
}

form {}

.editMenu {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sub-flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 33px;
}

.status-menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
}

.remaining-tasks {
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>To Do List</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="all" class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 inner">
        <h2>To Do List</h2>
        <form id="create-task">
          <input id="new-task-content" type="text" placeholder="new task" required/>
          <button>Create</button>
        </form>

        <div id='todo-list'>
        </div>
        <div class="status-menu">
          <p class="remaining-tasks">
            <p class="remaining-tasks"> :remaining tasks.</p>
          </p>
          <div class="sub-flex">
            <button id="all-btn" class="filter">All</button>
            <button id="active-btn" class="filter">Active</button>
            <button id="completed-btn" class="filter">Completed</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>


  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The link to the project is [enter link description here](https://legendary-salmiakki-5a4e5a.netlify.app/)

Answer (score 0):

change event to:

```
 $(document).on('click', ".mark-complete", function (e) {
    $('.task').each(function (i, el) {
      if ($(this).find('.mark-complete').prop('checked')) {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'rgba(36, 236, 36, 0.116)');
      }
    })
  });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.